# Ways to manage pods in different executing result

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have many one-shot dockers to generate an output file in my project, they are small but cost many resources, so k8s is the best choice. In this scenario, I start pods by `kubectl run --restart=Never` without any replication controllers. As a result, the output file is not guaranteed, and I have to handle them by myself including:

- remove succeeded pods.
- restart failed pods.

To remove succeeded pods, there seems no "--rm" argument in k8s as in the docker, nor the methods to pass into docker command, so `kubectl delete pods --all` should be the only choice. What's worse, all the pods status are `Error` or `ExitCode:0`, but fortunately, the output file generated successfully.

To restart failed pods, I really have no idea on that right now.

So, does it look silly, or is there any better solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove failed/succeeded pods

The kubelet has built in [garbage collecting](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/admin/garbage-collection.md) and exited containers from nodes. In addition, there is a gc controller to [clean the actual objects from etcd](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7660).

> restart failed pods.

The way one does this is via replication controller. Sounds like you want [restartPolicy=OnFailure](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/pod-states.md#restartpolicy)?

Comment: Thanks! The reason I'd like to use `restart=Never` is my pods are one-shot pods, and always return "Error" or "ExitCode:0" status, but I definitely get the output file after running. So if `restart=OnFailure`, they might always restart even have produced the files. btw, I've entered into the docker, and test the command, the exit code is 0, so do you know which exit code does the pod need to show the "Completed" or "Succeeed" status?

Comment: Comparing with `Jobs`, `RC`, I think add `restartPolicy=OnFailure` directly to the pod yaml is the appropriate solutions. Thank you!